# Получение информации с DOS-консоли

Tags: dos, delphi, pipes

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые эксперты. Очередной раз, собирая мозги по полу, обращаюсь к Вашей помощи. Тестирую приложение, помимо всего прочего во время исполнения считывается информация с консоли, и в это время происходит какая-то бяка. Нужно локализовать проблему, но я не могу не то что ее локализовать, я даже не могу понять, как работают эти трубки (pipes), а в инете нотаций классов TSecurityAttributes, TStartupInfo и пр. я что-то не нахожу. Вот кусок типичного по этой теме кода, прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, что там происходит или посоветуйте, где внятно описана эта тема.

```
function ipconfig(v_cmd:string):string; 
const BUFSIZE = 2000; 
var SecAttr: TSecurityAttributes; 
    hReadPipe, hWritePipe: THandle; 
    StartupInfo: TStartUpInfo; 
    ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation; 
    Buffer: Pchar; 
    WaitReason,BytesRead: DWord; 
    l_str:string; 
    i:integer; 
begin 
 with SecAttr do 
  begin 
   nlength:= SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes); 
   binherithandle:= true; 
   lpsecuritydescriptor:= nil; 
  end; 
 if Createpipe(hReadPipe, hWritePipe, @SecAttr, 0) then 
  begin 
   Buffer:= AllocMem(BUFSIZE + 1); 
   FillChar(StartupInfo, Sizeof(StartupInfo), #0); 
   StartupInfo.cb:= SizeOf(StartupInfo); 
   StartupInfo.hStdOutput:= hWritePipe; 
   StartupInfo.hStdInput:= hReadPipe; 
   StartupInfo.dwFlags:= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES + STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW; 
   StartupInfo.wShowWindow:= SW_HIDE; 
   if CreateProcess(nil, PChar('ipconfig '), @SecAttr, @SecAttr, true, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then 
    begin 
     repeat 
      WaitReason:= WaitForSingleObject( ProcessInfo.hProcess,100); 
      //Application.ProcessMessages; 
      //WriteLn( WaitReason); 
     until(WaitReason <> WAIT_TIMEOUT); 
     repeat 
      BytesRead := 0; 
      ReadFile(hReadPipe, Buffer[0], BUFSIZE, BytesRead, nil); 
      Buffer[BytesRead]:= #0; 
      OemToAnsi(Buffer,Buffer); 
      //Копим 
      l_str := l_str + String(buffer); 
     until(BytesRead < BUFSIZE); 
    end; 
   result:=l_str; 
   FreeMem(Buffer); 
   CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess); 
   CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread); 
   CloseHandle(hReadPipe); 
   CloseHandle(hWritePipe); 
  end; 
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Применяемые здесь StartUpInfo, SecurityAttributes и т.д. являются стандарными структурами и функциями Windows32 API. Документацию по ним можно найти на сайте MSDN ([prooflink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331(v=vs.85).aspx)).
Касательно же данной процедуры: она запускает программу ipconfig с настройками на вывод в т.н. трубки (pipes) - строка 26. Благодаря этому после завершения работы программы процедура может считать весь вывод ipconfig в консоль - строки 33 -38, и возвращает полученную строку.

Comment: Хотелось бы добавить, что WaitForSingleObject может вернуть значение WAIT_FAILED. Что не было здесь рассмотрено, а, как мне кажется, стоило бы.